# How to create a .vbs with multiple lines in batch?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, insert

Hi there I have this short code (Batch):

```
set "from= %date%"
set "to=10-01-2018"
echo Num1 = #%to%# - #%from%#>tmp1.vbs
echo Wscript.echo Num1/150*100>tmp1.vbs
```

But as i expected it overwrites the first line.. How do I copy multiple lines? Thanks!

Comment: `>` -----> `>>`

Comment: See answer by @compo below. That is the better method

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to this structure, it's easier to read and will echo all the lines in the parenthesised block to the redirection operator meaning that `>` should work fine for you.

```bat
Set "from=%DATE%"
Set "to=10-01-2018"
(
    Echo Num1 = #%to%# - #%from%#
    Echo Wscript.echo Num1/150*100

)>tmp1.vbs
```

Answer (score -1):

You can append the lines with `>>`.

While `>` will write to the file with the output given, `>>` will append the line given ti the file, so the second line of `echo` should use a `>>` to avoid overwriting.